# Is the order of payload installation undefined?

Tags: ios, configuration-profile

Configuration profiles could be installed on iOS (through iPCU, MDM, web an so on).

Each configuration profile may have multiple payloads. Based on the the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html), 
PayloadContent is an array of payloads.

I wonder, whether the order of payloads installation is predefined or undefined.

On one hand, if it's array, my assumption would be that they are installed in predefined order. On other hand, I didn't find any information on this subject.

Comment: While I can think of a few situations where installation order might conceivably matter, it's a bit contrived. It's also perfectly reasonable to iterate backwards through an array. iPCU also doesn't let you reorder payloads, and it's unwise to rely on undocumented features unless you can test it thoroughly and retest on every OS version you intend to support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, @tc who wrote a comment is right. It's better to not rely on undocumented functionality.

However, I experimented with this and found that payloads are installed in order in which they are specified in the array.

Probably, the only exception would be identity payload which are referenced by WiFi, VPN or MDM. However, I didn't try them.